# JQuery set select using .prop('selectedIndex', #) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, prop

I'm using the following line to set a option from a select menu:

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 2)
```

Using the following site as a example: 
http://shoebaloo.nl/michael-by-michael-kors-chelsea-skate-leo-bruin-dessin-285000097-women-sneakers.html

I am indeed seeing the select option going to the second option but it wont have the same effect as actually clicking on the second option.

Can someone help me so the page actually recognises me "clicking" on a option?

Comment: What does the HTML of your select look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the option with a selector.

```
$('select option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true)
```

If you're looking to manually trigger a click or change event, you could use the `.trigger('click')` or `.trigger('change')` methods.

http://jsfiddle.net/j5v6tp7t/4/

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt work. The page doesnt register it as actually selecting a option with a click..

Comment: What do you mean by the page registering it as a click?

Comment: If you go to the website mentioned as example and select size 35 you will see the button change from "in shopping bag" to "request availability".
When running the line it wont do that.

Comment: Use `$('select').trigger('change');`, because there's an onchange handler on the select.

Comment: Thank you! It was really bugging me

Answer (score 1):

All you should have to do is use `.val()` to set the value.

For example:

```js
$('select').val('2')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
    <option value="4">d</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt work. The page doesnt register it as actually selecting a option with a click..

Comment: You'll need to provide a complete code example as you can see the code here works. What are you looking for in terms of the page "registering" a click.

Comment: I am aware that the code you mentioned works but it doesnt work on the website I mentioned.
If you go to the website mentioned as example and select size 35 you will see the button change from "in shopping bag" to "request availability". When running the line it wont do that.

Comment: Yes, it most certainly does. In fact I tested it there first.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression was right but the correct syntax is :

```
$('select').get(0).selectedIndex = 2;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4s762cq/